# Permission denied when trying to stage changes on mapped network drive

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to stage changes on a network mapped drive on my computer, but receive this error message:

> error: unable to write sha1 filename .git/objects/blahblah: Permission denied

Note blahblah is inserted in place of an actual sha1 filename.

This is the setup of the development environment:

- My local machine is a Windows 10 machine running Sourcetree.
- We have a shared Mac Mini with MAMP PRO installed, which stores all our local code and repositories. I have mapped the root folder of MAMP to my machine for editing code.
- The user running the MAMP PRO server is the same user I have mapped the network drive with, this is the admin user of the Mac.

Sourcetree recognizes that the folder is a git repository and also displays any changes to files but doesn't allow me to stage any changes. The same error also appears when trying `git add -A` in the terminal.

Any help on this would be appreciated. I hate permissions and this is across different architectures, so pretty much my worst nightmare!